# R: 5 min intervals added to dataframe

Tags: r, aggregate, intervals

A quick overview of the intent.

- sensor: time of occurence & room when a sensor is triggered (pings)
- timeslot: structured 30min time windows per room to sort data into 
  Find the amount of pings in each 5min block PER room. Structure into desired table.

To note:

-Thare are 6 lots of 5min windows for each 30min block (0-5min,5-10min,10-15min etc)

-Each room is serperate to other rooms in terms of ping count

-This is a smaller version of a bigger set ( way more rooms, way more 30min blocks)

-If a value is 10:05:00am it belongs in the bracket "0 to 5 min" and not "5-10".
 - 10.05:01 belongs in "5 to 10 min"

Ideas: 
      if sensor$Room=timeslot$Room AND timeslot$ST < sensor$UTC =< timeslot$ET
....somehow have a count that is designated by which 5min block it belongs to. Run every row of "sensor" through as each iteration and the columns count.
I tried using the aggregate function before but it became to hard to fill in the rigid structure of the "desired" output.

```
> sensor
            UTC         pin  Room
 1  2014-12-22 10:14:34   1 Alpha
 2  2014-12-22 10:15:00   0 Alpha
 3  2014-12-22 10:15:25   0 Alpha
 4  2014-12-22 10:15:27   1 Alpha
 5  2014-12-22 10:16:00   1 Alpha
 6  2014-12-22 10:18:00   0 Alpha
 7  2014-12-22 10:18:03   0 Alpha
 8  2014-12-22 10:18:10   1 Alpha
 9  2014-12-22 10:18:39   0 Alpha
 10 2014-12-22 10:19:00   0 Alpha
 11 2014-12-22 10:19:04   0 Alpha
 12 2014-12-22 10:19:06   1 Alpha
 13 2014-12-22 10:20:00   1 Alpha
 14 2014-12-22 10:08:34   1  Beta
 15 2014-12-22 10:14:00   0  Beta
 16 2014-12-22 10:15:25   0  Beta
 17 2014-12-22 10:15:29   1  Beta
 18 2014-12-22 10:16:00   1  Beta
 19 2014-12-22 10:17:00   1  Beta
 20 2014-12-22 10:18:00   0  Beta
 21 2014-12-22 10:18:03   0  Beta
 22 2014-12-22 10:18:10   1  Beta
 23 2014-12-22 10:18:39   0  Beta
 24 2014-12-22 10:19:00   1  Beta
 25 2014-12-22 10:19:09   0  Beta
 26 2014-12-22 10:19:11   1  Beta
 27 2014-12-22 10:20:20   0  Beta
 28 2014-12-22 10:09:34   1 Gamma
 29 2014-12-22 10:39:11   1 Gamma


 > timeslot
    Room Capacity Video.Conference                  ST                  ET
 1 Alpha       16                1 2014-12-22 10:00:00 2014-12-22 10:30:00
 2 Alpha       16                1 2014-12-22 10:30:00 2014-12-22 11:00:00
 3  Beta       16                1 2014-12-22 10:00:00 2014-12-22 10:30:00
 4  Beta       16                1 2014-12-22 10:30:00 2014-12-22 11:00:00
 5 Gamma       10                0 2014-12-22 10:00:00 2014-12-22 10:30:00
 6 Gamma       10                0 2014-12-22 10:30:00 2014-12-22 11:00:00


>Desired #This is the intended output
 X  Room Capacity Vid                  ST              ET       X0.to.5.min X5.to.10.min  X10.to.15.min  X15.to.20.min  X20.to.25.min  X25.to.30.min  sum
 1  Alpha       16   1 2014-12-22 10:00:00 2014-12-22 10:30:00           0            0             1             6             0             0       7
 2  Alpha       16   1 2014-12-22 10:30:00 2014-12-22 11:00:00           0            0             0             0             0             0       0
 3   Beta       16   1 2014-12-22 10:00:00 2014-12-22 10:30:00           1            0             0             6             0             0       7
 4   Beta       16   1 2014-12-22 10:30:00 2014-12-22 11:00:00           0            0             0             0             0             0       0
 5  Gamma       10   0 2014-12-22 10:00:00 2014-12-22 10:30:00           1            0             0             0             0             0       1
 6  Gamma       10   0 2014-12-22 10:30:00 2014-12-22 11:00:00           0            1             0             0             0             0       1
```

This is WAY beyond my skillset so any help would be greatly appreciated

****dputs added

```
>dput(timeslot)

structure(list(Room = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Alpha", 
"Beta", "Gamma"), class = "factor"), Capacity = c(16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 10L, 10L), Video.Conference = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), 
ST = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("2014-12-22 10:00:00", 
"2014-12-22 10:30:00"), class = "factor"), ET = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("2014-12-22 10:30:00", "2014-12-22 11:00:00"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Room", "Capacity", "Video.Conference", 
"ST", "ET"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

> dput(sensor)

structure(list(UTC = structure(c(4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 20L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 18L, 19L, 21L, 2L, 22L), .Label = c("2014-12-22 10:08:34", 
"2014-12-22 10:09:34", "2014-12-22 10:14:00", "2014-12-22 10:14:34", 
"2014-12-22 10:15:00", "2014-12-22 10:15:25", "2014-12-22 10:15:27", 
"2014-12-22 10:15:29", "2014-12-22 10:16:00", "2014-12-22 10:17:00", 
"2014-12-22 10:18:00", "2014-12-22 10:18:03", "2014-12-22 10:18:10", 
"2014-12-22 10:18:39", "2014-12-22 10:19:00", "2014-12-22 10:19:04", 
"2014-12-22 10:19:06", "2014-12-22 10:19:09", "2014-12-22 10:19:11", 
"2014-12-22 10:20:00", "2014-12-22 10:20:20", "2014-12-22 10:39:11"
), class = "factor"), pin = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), Room = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("UTC", "pin", "Room"), row.names = c(NA, 
-29L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way. I am sure there are better ways to do this work. But, this could be something you could further arrange for your larger data set.

```
library(dplyr) # I use the dev version, dplyr 0.4
library(tidyr)
library(chron)

### Arrange sensor
sensor <- mutate(sensor, UTC = as.POSIXct(UTC, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                         minute = as.numeric(format(UTC, "%M")),
                         minute = ifelse(minute >= 30, minute-30, minute),
                         sub.group = as.character(cut(minute,
                                                      breaks = c(0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30),
                                                      labels = c("0-5", "5-10", "10-15", "15-20", "20-25", "25-30"))),
                         time = times(as.character(format(UTC, "%H:%M:%S"))),
                         time = as.character(cut(time,
                                                 breaks = times(c("10:00:00", "10:30:00", "11:00:00")),
                                                 labels = c("a", "b"))),
                         Room = as.character(Room))

### Create a master df
master <- data.frame(Room = rep(c("Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma"), each = 6),
                     time = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 18),
                     sub.group = rep(c("0-5", "5-10", "10-15",
                                       "15-20", "20-25", "25-30"), times = 3),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

### Get an outcome
df1 <- full_join(summarise(group_by(sensor, Room,time, sub.group), total = sum(pin)),
                 master, by = c("Room","time", "sub.group")) %>%
       spread(sub.group, total, fill = 0)


### Arrange timeslot for join
timeslot <- mutate_each(timeslot,funs(as.POSIXct(., format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")), ST:ET) %>%
            mutate(time = as.character(format(ST, "%M")),
                   time = ifelse(time == "00", "a", "b"),
                   Room = as.character(Room))

### join again
final <- full_join(timeslot, df1, by = c("Room", "time")) %>%
         select(-time)

### Order columns
final <- final[, c(1:6, 11, 7:10)]

### Get row sum
mutate(final, total = rowSums(final[, c(6:11)]))

#   Room Capacity Video.Conference                  ST                  ET 0-5 5-10 10-15 15-20 20-25 25-30 total
#1 Alpha       16                1 2014-12-22 10:00:00 2014-12-22 10:30:00   0    0     2     4     0     0     6
#2 Alpha       16                1 2014-12-22 10:30:00 2014-12-22 11:00:00   0    0     0     0     0     0     0
#3  Beta       16                1 2014-12-22 10:00:00 2014-12-22 10:30:00   0    1     1     5     0     0     7
#4  Beta       16                1 2014-12-22 10:30:00 2014-12-22 11:00:00   0    0     0     0     0     0     0
#5 Gamma       10                0 2014-12-22 10:00:00 2014-12-22 10:30:00   0    1     0     0     0     0     1
#6 Gamma       10                0 2014-12-22 10:30:00 2014-12-22 11:00:00   0    1     0     0     0     0     1
```